# manipulating arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays like so

```
var arr1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
var arr2 = [["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["e", "f", "g", "h"], ["i", "j", "k", "l"], ["m", "n", "o", "p"], ["q", "r", "s", "t"]];
```

What I would like to do is merge the two arrays to form a final output that looks like this

```
var newArr = [{1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c", 4: "d"}, {1: "e", 2: "f", 3: "g", 4: "h"}, {1: "i", 2: "j", 3: "k", 4: "l"}, {1: "m", 2: "n", 3: "o", 4: "p"}, {1: "q", 2: "r", 3: "s", 4: "t"}];
```

So effectively take each array out of the second array and then merge it with the first array to form an object.

I was just wandering what the most efficient way to do this in javascript would be?

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks for your time

Comment: You can use `.forEach` or `.map()` to achieve this.

Comment: _what the most efficient way to do this.._ It depends on what you exactly mean by "efficient". If you mean speed, then obviously the only way is iterating through arrays. If you mean readabilty, I would suggest to use utility library such as Underscore.

Comment: @hindmost I suppose I meant the best way to achieve my desired outcome

Comment: @BeeNag "the best way" is always opinion-based thing. That's why you need clarify the "efficiency". Otherwise it would look like off-topic.

Comment: It looks like zipping. Check lodash's `zipObject` function https://lodash.com/docs#zipObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input always matches, I'd start with `arr2`:

```
arr2.map(x =>
```

However, at this point what you want is to `zip` values from `x` and the corresponding values from `y` together, so let's introduce a helper first (I'm actually gonna call it `zipKeyVal`<sup>1</sup> because it maps values from first param to keys, and the second to values).

```
function zipKeyVal(keys,values) {
    var result = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        result[keys[i]] = values[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

With that, our solution becomes:

```
var newArr = arr2.map(x => zipKeyVal(arr1, x));
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Oh, apparently underscore.js calls that `_.object`, and lodash `zipObject`.</sub>

Comment: Nice functional approach.

Comment: Also, [If you return a function from `zipKeyVal`](https://jsfiddle.net/knpn18t4/) you can simply do `var newArr = arr2.map(zipKeyVal(arr1));`

Comment: @Andy I guess curried functions aren't really used a lot in the JS world.

Comment: Whilst all the answers provided work I am selecting this one as the correct answer as I like the approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some array methods like [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and 
[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
var arr1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
    arr2 = [["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["e", "f", "g", "h"], ["i", "j", "k", "l"], ["m", "n", "o", "p"], ["q", "r", "s", "t"]],
    newArr = arr2.map(function (a) {
        var o = {};
        arr1.forEach(function (b, i) {
            o[b] = a[i];
        });
        return o;
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newArr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use two `map` functions and some ES6 features:

```
var newArr = arr2.map(el => el.map((e, i) => ({ [arr1[i]]: e })));
```

Working example:

```js
var arr1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
var arr2 = [ ["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["e", "f", "g", "h"], ["i", "j", "k", "l"], ["m", "n", "o", "p"], ["q", "r", "s", "t"] ];

var newArr = arr2.map(el => el.map((e, i) => ({ [arr1[i]]: e })));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newArr, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Underscore:

```
var newArr = _.map(arr2, function(arr) {
    return _.object(arr1, arr);
});
```

Comment: With the ES6 syntax this gets the cleanest one-liner: `_.map(arr2, arr => _.object(arr1, arr));`